# How is first-order logic complete but not decidable?

Tags: first-order-logic

Why doesn't completeness imply decidability for first-order logic?

First order logic is complete, which means (I think) given a set of sentences A and a sentence B, then either B or ~B can be arrived at through the rules of inference being applied to A. If B is arrived at, then A implies B in every interpretation. If ~B is arrived at, then A implies ~B in every interpretation.

First order logic is undecidable, which means (again, I think) that given a set of sentences A and a sentence B, there is no procedure for determining whether A implies B (i.e. it's not the case that A are true and B is false) in all interpretations.

Why doesn't this work: Enumerate all strings x. If x encodes the valid derivation of B from A, accept. If x encodes the valid derivation of ~B from A, reject.

Because of completeness, eventually this process will stumble across an x which is either a proof of B or ~B from A. If B, then A implies B in all interpretations. If ~B, then it is not the case that A implies B in all interpretations. So FOL is decidable. But it's not, so I must have the wrong definition of either completeness or decidability.

Comment: For some reason, I think that "It is not the case that B can be derived from A" implies "~B can be derived from A." I think that's where I'm misunderstanding completeness. That's clearly not true, because when A is {R(x)} and B is S(x), there there exists an interpretation in which A are true and B is false, and in which A are true and B is true. So neither B or ~B can be proven from A.

Comment: So, is this a better understanding? There's a procedure that will tell us, supposing either (1) B is implied by A in every interpretation or (2) ~B is implied by A in every interpretation, which of (1) or (2) is the case, but in the case where neither (1) or (2) or true, there is no procedure for deciding if B is true in a *specific* interpretation.

Comment: This is not an issue of philosophy but of mathematics. Therefore, this should be on [cs.SE] (because computability is part of CS) or maybe [math.SE].

Comment: @Raphael Properties of logics are being discussed repeatedly in entries in the Stanford Encyclopedia or Philosophy, like here: [The Completeness Theorem](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel/#ComThe) or in books like "The Blackwell Encyclopedia of [Philosophical Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_logic)". So, yes, "philosophy".

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Maybe I don't understand what Philosophy is, but I didn't think it included a lot of mathematical, rigorous definitions. Unlike this question and its answer, which are all about such definitions.

Comment: The simple answer is of course that the sentence X about which you ask the question may neither be "universally valid" (true in all interpretations of the symbols) nor "unsatisifiable" (false in all interpretations of the symbols) but true only for some interpretations. So if you have two a special universe with infinite time, infinite tape, infinite energy and infinite heat sink ("Unlimited Tape Works" universe) and two Turing Machines therein, one trying to prove A and trying to prove ~A by enumeration of classical logic proof trees, none of those two TMs will ever hit a valid proof.

Comment: ...and this assumes that there is no (perfect, always returning the good answer in finite time) TM that can give an "upper bound" on the length of the proof so that the two searching TMs can never say "I searched far enough, and can stop: there is no proof" with absolute certainty. I haven't though about this, but the existence of such a TM would probably mean that the Haltingproblem could be perfectly solved (imperfect TMs that solve the Halting Problem imperfectly and "in some practical cases" exist of course) which we know can't be done with TMs. Hence, "undecidability".

Comment: @Raphael Well, a good part of philosophy (I would say the "serious part" outside of pointless metaphysical musings or frankly horrific stuff - Hegel, I'm looking you) has always been the driver for new directions in mathematics and logic and continues to do so, check out [Philosophy of Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philosophy-mathematics/). So, both knowledge areas are really joined at the hip.

Comment: First order logic (tautologies) is not complete and not decidable (but semidecidable): for instance “Axioms of Robinson arithmetic imply inconsistency of Robinson arithmetic” (translated to a formula of FOL, using some encoding for the inconsistency predicate) is a sentence that in some metatheories -eg Robinson arithmetic Q- is not provable, and so is its negation, assuming Q is consistent. You may take any finitely axiomatized theory -like NBG- to make similar undecidable sentences. Church and Turing also proved undecidability of FOL, by encoding Turing machines as FOL sentences.

Answer (score 35):

**NO**, completeness of first-order logic does not imply decidability.

You are mixing two use of *completeness*.

The first use regards the completeness of "standard" proof systems for [first-order logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/).

This is [Gödel's Completeness Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem), that says :

> The completeness theorem says that if a formula is *logically valid* then there is a finite deduction (a formal proof) of the formula.
>
> Gödel's completeness theorem says that a deductive system of first-order predicate calculus is "complete" in the sense that no additional inference rules are required to prove all the logically valid formulas. A converse to completeness is soundness, the fact that only logically valid formulas are provable in the deductive system. Together with soundness (whose verification is easy), this theorem implies that a formula is logically valid if and only if it is the conclusion of a formal deduction.

It is easily generalized to the relation of [logical consequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence) between a set **Γ** of first-order formulas and a formula **φ**, in symbols :

> **Γ ⊨ φ**.

In this case we have that :

**Γ ⊨ φ** iff **Γ ⊢ φ** (i.e. **φ** is *provable* from **Γ**).

For simplicity, we will consider the case when **Γ** is the emptyset; in this case we have the previous version :

**⊨ φ** (i.e. **φ** is [valid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity)) iff **⊢ φ** (i.e. **φ** is *provable*).

Your fallacy regards the "basic property" of *validity* :

> > it is not true that if **φ** is **not** *valid* then **¬φ** is *valid*.

Consider the formula :

> ∃x∃y ¬(x = y).

It means : "there are at least two thing x and y such that they are not equal". This formula is not true in a *universe* with only a single element. Thus, it is not valid (validity means : true in every universe).

Its negation is :

> ¬∃x∃y ¬(x = y)

which amounts to :

> ∀x∀y (x = y).

It means "all things are equal". Neither this formula is valid, because it is not true in a universe with more than one element.

---

Compare with [propositional logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus), where a valid formula is called a [tautology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)) (the negation of a tautology is called a *contradiction* : a formula which is always false).

In this case, we have a *decision procedure* : the [truth-table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) algorithm (it is highly "inefficient", but it works ...).

Apply it to a formula **A** whatever : if in its column you have all "T", then the formula is a *tautology*.

Also in this case there is a completeness theorem : if **A** is a tautology, we can find a proof of it in the "usual" proof systems, like *Natural Deduction*.

But note that also in this case it is **not** true that, for a formula **A** whatever, **A** is a tautology or **¬A** is.

The formula :

> p V q

is neither a tautology nor a contradiction.

---

The second meaning of *completeness* regards *theories*, and is the key to the famous [Gödel's incompleteness theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems) which says that :

> The first incompleteness theorem states that no consistent system of axioms whose theorems can be listed by an "effective procedure" (e.g., a computer program, but it could be any sort of algorithm) is capable of proving all truths about the relations of the natural numbers (arithmetic). For any such system, there will always be statements about the natural numbers that are true, but that are unprovable within the system.

This (negative) result concerns another aspect of intuitive "completeness" (in the sense of adequacy) : for a mathematical theory, like arithmetic or set theory, it is a reasonable expectation that the axioms (formalized with first-order logic) are able to "capture" all the mathematical truth expressible in that theory.

For most of "little bit complex" mathematical theories, this is not possible.

---

*Added*

[Decidability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_(logic)) is linked to the second meaning of *completeness*.

If a theory **T** is complete in the second sense above, i.e. **T** is able to prove all true sentences **φ** expressible in the language of the theory, due to the fact that either **φ** is true in **T** or **¬φ** is true in **T**, **and** is effectively axiomatized, then **T** is *decidable*.

[*Note*. If we consider the two formulae above, and we consider their meaning regarding the single arithmetical interpretation, now we have that one of them is true and the other is false. Due to the fact that there are infinite natural numbers (and so, more than one), we have that the formula : ∃x∃y ¬(x = y) is true in the arithmetical interpretation (consider e.g. **1** and **2**), while its denial ∀x∀y (x = y) is obviously false (not all numbers are equal)].

Going back to decidability, why a complete theory is so ?

Exactly because the "procedure" described in your question works : start proving theorems in **T**. After a finite amount of time, if **φ** is true, you will find the proof of it; if it is not, then **¬φ** is true and you will find a proof of it.

As said before, this "procedure" does not work for *validity* because it is not true that either a formula or its denial are valid.

Gödel's incompleteness theorem proves that formalized theories having enough "capability" for expressing arithmetical facts are not *complete* in the second sense : they are not able to "capture" all true arithmetical facts.

Thus the above theories are **not** decidable.

---

What is the "link" between the two uses of *completeness* ?

Consider a first-order theory **T** which include the language of arithmetic.

The "underlying" f-o logic is complete (first sense) : i.e. it is able to prove **all** *logical consequences* of the axioms of the theory **T**.

But the theory **T** is *incomplete* (according to Gödel's incompleteness theorem), i.e. there is a true arithmetical sentence **φ** not provable from the axioms of **T**.

So what ?

It is not a contradiction. Consider the def of logical consequence applied to **T** :

> **T ⊨ φ** iff **φ** is true in every model of **T**.

Being **φ** true in the "intended model" of arithmetic (the "usual" numbers) we conclude that it is **not** true in some other model [see Francis Davey's comment]: there are [non-standard model of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic).

Being so, it is **not** a logical consequence of the axioms of **T** and this is the reason why its *unprovability* in **T** does not conflict with the completeness of the underlying logic.

Comment: Does it follow that a Gödel sentence is true in some interpretations, but false in others?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right. It demonstrates that there are non-standard models of arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks, it's starting to make a lot more sense. I *was* confusing the two different completenesses. So, the first means: if a formula is valid (true in every interpretation), then it is provable. Decidability is about whether a formula is true in a specific interpretation, which is possible without it being valid. The second meaning of "completeness" is used in a claim within a specific (but arbitrary, therefore generalizable) set of axioms.

Comment: Is it possible for a system to be complete by the first meaning, but have interpretations which are incomplete by the second meaning? Or am I comparing apples to oranges by asking that question?

Comment: The second meaning of 'complete' (that there exist closed sentences that are not provable and whose negations are also not provable) applies to theories, not to interpretations.

Comment: @Mauro_ALLEGRANZA Regarding, your second definition of completeness, the syntactically complete theory can also be undecidable, right? As in, the theory of True Arithmetic?

Comment: So my takeaway is that f-o logic is incomplete (in Godel's sense) because Godel uses a broader definition of "model", while the completeness (in the first sense) has a narrow definition of "model". Is this correct?

Comment: If i read you correctly you state that a complete theory is decidable, but this is false. You further clarify « After a finite amount of time, if φ is true, you will find the proof of it; if it is not, then ¬φ is true and you will find a proof of it. », equivalently false. Decidability implies completeness but the converse is not true. For instance (given a metatheory, like ZF,) what is called "true arithmetic" (the set of sentences satisfied by the standard natural numbers) is complete, but undecidable. It is also not semidecidable -thus does not have a recursively enumerable set of axioms.

Comment: @plm - Thanks, tried to write it better... I've written "complete **and** effectively axiomatized" in which case  "true arithmetic" is ruled out.

Comment: Much obliged monsieur/mademoiselle, as the case may be. It appears that *completeness* is defined differently in the sense that for *first-order logic*, it *includes* the *set of valid deductive forms*, over and above *all grammatically correct and true statements that can be formulated* in the system.  Last I checked, Gödel's incompleteness theorems say nothing about the *logic*, instead focusing on *valid formulae* in mathematics. Kindly educate me on the difference.

Comment: Hi @MauroALLEGRANZA, thank you. I must correct myself too: decidability does not imply completeness, in a decidable incomplete theory the set of true sentences is recursive with some sentences and their negations rejected -as happens for the theory of algebraically closed fields. Sorry, as it was not relevant to the quote i commented i was careless.

Answer (score 10):

Since  Taylor Hornby already self-corrected the definition of completeness (thanks to Mauro ALLEGRANZA's first definition), I just want to point out where exactly his reasoning goes astray.

Why doesn't completeness imply decidability for first order logic? Taylor Hornby reasons as follows:

> Why doesn't this work: Enumerate all strings x. If x encodes the valid
>   derivation of B from A, accept. If x encodes the valid derivation of
>   ~B from A, reject.
>
> Because of completeness, eventually this process will stumble across
>   an x which is either a proof of B or ~B from A. If B, then A implies B
>   in all interpretations. If ~B, then it is not the case that A implies
>   B in all interpretations. So FOL is decidable.

what is wrong here is the sentence:

> Because of completeness, eventually this process will stumble across
>   an x which is either a proof of B or ~B from A.

Completeness by definition means "If B is logically entailed, then B is provable." It is a conditional statement. Now, in general, we do not know whether a given B is logically entailed or not in advance. So we do not know whether there is a proof of B or not. So what really happens is this:

> eventually this process will stumble across an x which is either a proof of B or ~B from A, OR this process will continue to run forever.

That is, this algorithm does not always determine whether B is logically entailed (or equivalently, whether B is provable, thanks to the properties of soundness and completeness of FOL). If either B or ~B is provable, we will eventually find its proof. But if neither B nor ~B is provable then we can never tell whether there is no proof or whether we just need to keep looking. So this algorithm does not give us an answer for every B, but we can ask whether there is a better algorithm that does give us an answer for every B. Turing's halting problem is used to show that there is no algorithm for determining whether B is logically entailed.

First-order logic is complete because all entailed statements are provable, but is undecidable because there is no algorithm for deciding whether a given sentence is or is not logically entailed.

Answer (score 0):

There are ultimate limits to machines, no matter how cleverly they are designed. In 1936, Turing proved mathematically that a general algorithm to solve the problem for all possible program-input pairs cannot exist, ever. That is, no algorithm can be written such that it will always correctly decide, for any given program-input pair, whether the program will or will not halt. In computer science, this is called the halting problem. Turing proved that any algorithm can be made to contradict itself and therefore cannot decide correctly. As an illustration, we may make use of a “pathological” program-input pair designed to do the opposite of what the algorithm predicts it will do.

Turing’s proof implies that it is impossible to predict if the Turing machine programmed to attack certain mathematical problems will ever succeed and come to a halt, or keep on running forever. Actually, an equivalent ultimate limit applies to humans: It is also impossible to predict if mathematicians will ever succeed with regard to solving these same problems.

The crucial question concerns completeness and decidability (as to whether a theorem is either true or false, but not both), which is equivalent to the halting problem in computing science. Incompleteness opens the door to the possibility of undecidability. A successful proof of a particular problem implies that it is not undecidable in the theory (or system) where it is formulated. But such a proof does not imply that the theory itself is complete or decidable. There may be other problems in the theory that are undecidable, in which case no solution exists. In an incomplete theory, there are theorems or equations, for instance, that appears to intuitively true but are unprovable. Therefore, it is impossible to predict if a particular problem formulated in an incomplete theory can ever be solved. Never before in the history of human knowledge has an ultimate limit to predictability been stated with such clarity, with the help of logician-mathematicians in the 20th century.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is correct, but not 100% confident:

One possible confusion is that we may think we are talking about a single model, when we're really talking about all possible models that satisfy a particular set of axioms. So if we are talking about one model, then P or NOT P is true, but if we are talking about multiple then P may be valid, NOT P may be valid or it may be mixed (here valid = always true).

Completeness means that if P is valid we'll prove it eventually and since NOT P is just another proposition, if it is valid same for that. However, this doesn't guarantee anything about the mixed propositions. We can never know that if we didn't just keep looking for longer that we wouldn't find a proof for P or for NOT P.

Or to clarify even more, the following two claims are different:

- "NOT P" is valid
- NOT "P is valid"

The later also includes P being mixed

Answer (score 0):

First order logic is just algebra, in disguise, while higher order logic is analysis. Theories formulated in first order logic can be expressed as algebraic systems: a system which contains a set of operations, a set of distinguished objects, and a set of equational identities; while theories formulated in higher-order logic that are not equivalently expressible or reducible to first-order theories, may be rightly regarded as calculi.

For instance, an Abelian group can be expressed as an algebra containing a single operation ("-" for subtraction), a distinguished object ("0"), and the following identities: 0 - 0 = 0, x - (x - y) = y and x - (y - z) = z - (y - x).

Also, for instance, an Affine Geometry A over a specific field F can be expressed as a two-sorted algebra containing the ternary operators a,f,b ∈ A×F×A ↦ [a,f,b] ∈ A and a,b,c ∈ A×A×A ↦ abc ∈ A that embodies the operations [a,f,b] = (1 - f)a + fb and abc = a - b + c. An example of axioms (suitable, except for the two fields F = GF(2) of size 2 and F = GF(3) of size 3) is: [a,0,b] = a, [a,1,b] = b, [a,rt(1-t),[b,s,c]] = [[a,rt(1-s),b],t,[a,rs(1-t),c]], abc = [[b,1/(1-t),a],t,[b,1/t,c]], where t is arbitrarily chosen as any member of the field F other than 0 or 1.

For algebraic theories, the "free algebra" is the one which contains just the distinguished objects and whatever other objects can be made from them using the algebra's operations. One can also talk about the "free algebra generated from a set X", where the members of the set X are added to the list of distinguished objects. For instance, the subtraction algebra, above, freely generated from the set {1} is one and the same as the algebra of integer subtraction, and contains also the algebra of integer addition by way of the definitions, -x = (x - x) - x, and x + y = x - (-y). (One can prove x - x = 0 using the axioms, namely by: x = 0 - (0 - x) = x - (0 - 0) = x - 0, and x - x = x - (x - 0) = 0, so -x = 0 - x is an equivalent definition, but less self-contained.)

So, first-order theories can always be realized by models, which makes first order logic complete. This is more precisely stated in the abstract, excerpted below, to "First-Order Theories as Many-Sorted Algebras" (Notre Dame Journal Of Formal Logic 25(1), January 1984 https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38355700_First-order_theories_as_many-sorted_algebras)

Completeness ensures that a proof for any valid statement can be found by a finite search. Failure to find a proof, when a statement is invalid, occurs only after the unending search through all possible proofs never ends. So, you would have to wait for forever to never end, first, before seeing a "no" answer to the query "is it valid?". In order to be decidable, the "no" answer has to be forthcoming some time before forever is never finished happening.

The key excerpt from the abstract:

"In this paper, by developing the study of first-order logic through many-sorted algebras, we show that every first-order theory is a particular algebra verifying axioms in equational form (see Section 2); therefore we are able to apply Birkhoff's theorems concerning the varieties (see Section 1 [and two references contained in the paper]) and to obtain the Henkin models algebraically, whence the completeness theorem of first-order logic (see Section 3)."

Punchline: "Many-sorted" is the key-phrase - so, add in a boolean type and remake predicates as boolean-valued operators.